# Rotate jqplot or any other jquery plot by 90 degree

Tags: jquery, canvas, jqplot

I would like to display a plot after rotating by 90 degree. I prefer any jquery based plotting tool.

[image]

Fig. 1 is diagram of the normal plot

[image]

Fig. 2 is diagram that want to have by rotating Fig. 1

As I see jqplot is using multiple canvas to draw the plot. If someone can help me by showing a way to rotate a div continer of the canvases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about jqplot, but you can rotate any div using css tranforms: http://w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 2):

I created a vertical jqplot chart using CSS rules, but it also has some issues.

You can view my blog post about it here,

http://gayashan-a.blogspot.de/2012/08/simple-dynamically-updating-line-chart.html

These are the issues i have encountered so far:

- Tracking the cursor causes problems because it doesn't seem to know that the div has been rotated.
- Unable to click on a point when the div is rotated.

If these are not problems for you can use the CSS rules to have a 90 degrees rotated jqplot chart.